# put superset data into google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, apache-superset

Is there any way that can put data in superset database into google sheets? I would like to extract some data, which may refresh every data, from superset database and put thoes data into google sheets

Any google sheets adds-on can do this?

Comment: Did you read the help topic on Superset [Google Sheets - Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/google-sheets/)?